# excel trim function is removing spaces in middle of text - this was unexpected (?)

Tags: excel-formula

The excel trim function is removing spaces in middle of text - this was unexpected (?)
i.e. I thought that the excel trim was for trimming leading and trailing spaces.
e.g. a cell value of =Trim("Last Obs  Resp") becomes a value of "Last Obs Resp"

Sure enough Microsoft documents it this way:
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9

I am used to the Oracle database trim function which only removes leading and trailing spaces.
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php

Was excel Trim function always this way?

Excel does not have ltrim and rtrim functions..
i.e. I can't do: 
=RTRIM(Ltrim("Last Obs  Resp"))

I wonder how I achieve the equivalent in Excel when I don't want to remove doubled up spaces in the middle of the string?

This page documents VBA trim function:
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php

Comment: You will need vba, vba `Trim` only trims leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I thought I noticed that a few years ago, but thought it was a bug. I had it again today though and found only one site that describes Excel's trim as removing all leading and trailing spaces, as well as all duplicate spaces between words. The last part was completely unexpected for a "trim" function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a UDF that uses VBA's version of Trim which does not touch the inner spaces.  Only removing the leading and trailing spaces

```
Function MyTrim(str As String) As String
    MyTrim = Trim(str)
End Function
```

Then you can call it from the worksheet:

```
=MyTrim(A1)
```

---

If you want a formula to do it:

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)))/(MID(A1,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1))),1)<>" "),1)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)))/(MID(A1,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1))),1)<>" "),1),999)
```

[image]

Comment: The UDF looks to be the easier of these 2 .. :) .. This works for me ..  Thank you